# Jquery file upload catch on complete of upload action

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I'm using [Jquery file upload by blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) want to catch an action that happens after upload of file.
So, this works fine

```
.on('change','input[type=file]',function(e)
{
    console.log('OOOOOOOOk');
})
```

But it's not working for me, because I need action after file upload completed.
So, in [docs](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options) I've found this solution:

```
var url = './fileUpload/jQuery-File-Upload/server/php/';
      $('#fileupload').fileupload({
          url: url,
          dataType: 'json',
          done: function (e, data) {
              $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                  $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
              });
          },
          progressall: function (e, data) {
              var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
              $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                  'width',
                  progress + '%'
              );
          }
      }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
          .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled')
          .bind('fileuploadcompleted',function(e,data)
            {
              console.log('eventFinished');
            });
```

But I dont see eventFinished string in console after uploading, but see OOOOOOOk. How can I catch this event then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding the 'fileuploadcompleted' event to the parent of actual element, so try re-arranging the code in this way.

```
var url = './fileUpload/jQuery-File-Upload/server/php/';
  $('#fileupload').fileupload({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      done: function (e, data) {
          $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
              $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
          });
      },
      progressall: function (e, data) {
          var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
          $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
              'width',
              progress + '%'
          );
      }
  }).bind('fileuploadcompleted',function(e,data)
        {
          console.log('eventFinished');
        }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
      .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
```

Comment: are you using the UI version of Jquery file upload by blueimp ? if not, then use this event instead 'fileuploaddone'